# Declaring variables as static within MainActivity and accessing them from other classes

Tags: java, android

Many times when I have been developing android apps, in order to access some important variables such as **getApplicationContext()** or other variables such as *Buttons* or *Edittexts*, which are normally *not accessible outside MainActivity* but *required in some other class* in the **same** project, I have been using this technique, that is

*Within MainActivity* **(for getApplicationContext() case)**:

```
private static Context context = null;
```

and inside the *onCreate* method, I do :

```
context = getApplicationContext();
```

and I then access the context ( to display a toast message , for example) by using:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.context,"Message",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

in my other class. Similarly to **get** or **set** the text in an *EditText* variable and so on.

My questions are:

1)Is this the best method for my problem definition?

2)If no, is there a better way?

3)if no, what are the disadvantages of this technique?

3)Can the same technique be extended to *functions* in the Mainctivity?

**EDIT**: I do **not** require another Activity here, rather I am just *splitting* the task of the app into *separate* classes (or objects).

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "a static class"? In Java, "static class" only refers to nested types, which does *not* mean that the class isn't instantiated. Assuming that `MainActivity` is really an activity, it *is* going to be instantiated...

Comment: Okay that part was wrong (I have edited), but this method has worked out perfectly so far. Basically MainActivity is a class whose function *OnCreate* is where the Android app execution begins. Generally, the MainActivity is not *explicity* instantiated.

Answer (score 4):

My questions are:

1)Is this the best method for my problem definition?

no this is not the best way of solving this.

2)If no, is there a better way?

yes to save static information you should be using something like a headless fragment so that the android framework can handle the garbage collection on unused classes and data

3)if no, what are the disadvantages of this technique?

disadvantages are many :) firstly memory leaking cause that static var cant be garbage collected at all so it stays in memory.
secondly you should not use edit texts from the main activity somewhere else cause there is no garantee that the mainactivity will still be there cause if you move away from it android might kill it to save memory.
all screens should be selfcontained and data must be transfered with intents and Bundles()

3)Can the same technique be extended to functions in the Mainctivity?

create seperate helper classes that sit within a static class like helpers. MainActivity is not a static class and shouldn't be a static class

Comment: Thanks for the reply and useful answer. Please check my edit and tell me, is the method OK in that case, because I will not require any intents in that case.